# Multiple connections to one SignalR hub from AngularJS client

Tags: c#, angularjs, websocket, signalr

I have an AngularJS application. Let's say I have different views with different controllers. In each controller I want to use data from the same SignalR server hub.

What are best practices to manage the hub connections:

- I start a new connection (`connection.start()`) to the hub in every
  controller. Is there any problem to have multiple connections to the
  same hub?
- I open the connection to the hub once at innitializing the app and
  then I can use these connection in the controllers.

Should I close the connection when I'm not using the data from the hub in the current view and reopen the connection when I'm back to the view? Or is there no problem to have multiple connections open even though I'm not using all connections at every time?

Comment: SignalR server can accept multiple connections. You can close and establish a new connections from clients. Can you give more details about your case, as it looks pretty general question.

Comment: @RamiYampolsky E.g. I have two views, each has a chart. I open the first view. I start the connection to the hub and I get the data from the server for that first view. Now I switch to the second view. My question was, should I close the connection for the first view (because I dont need the data for the second view)? And is there any problem to open a second connection tu the same hub to get the data from the server for the second view?

Comment: You can but don't have to close connection to the first view. The classic example for SignalR is chat room, all of the clients can be connected at the same room, as well disconnect and reconnect to the chat room.

Comment: @RamiYampolsky Yes, but in your example, there are multiple clients with just one connection to the hub. That is nor problem for the hub. But is there any performance problem on client side, if you have multiple connections to the hub from just one client?

Comment: Now it is not related to SignalR. The bottle neck can be the network if you pass large data at the same time. Connection maintenance "heartbit" of the non-busy client would not harm the performance for the busy client

Answer (score 1):

Based on SignalR's documentation, it will use the same connection because it's the same client.  however, the way you describe it, recreating the connection.start on each controller is probably not the way i'd suggest doing it.

I implemented something like this:
https://dzone.com/articles/better-way-using-aspnet

which has a service, and uses $scope.$parent.$on('',function(){}); in each of the controllers.  This also allows you to only watch certain events on each controller you care about. and let the service watch everything and 'emit' the events to the controllers that care.  at the bottom of the controller you'd call {signalrservicename}.intialize() like that article describes.  The most efficient and best way to share 'data' with angular controllers is by

1) using $rootScope.$emit like this article describes along with a service
OR

2) simply using one service that shares all the events for your application, and never uses $rootScope.$emit. this would require your service have 'extensive knowledge' of each controller, and this sometimes just isn't practical.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the websocket to send data from the server to the client, then you should keep the connection open.

if you want to limit the number of connection from the same session to the server, you can create one connection from the same App and store the data into the $rootscope, each controller can then watch a global variable and get the information from it if they are listening to the same changes. Otherwise I think have multiple connections is fine.

Comment: I don't want to limit the connections. Only if there are performance issues when I'm having multiple connections to the same hub. If so, then I want to limit the connections.